# On route change view scroll to top in the new page in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll

I have tried this.$router.replace(…) on the router-link but does't seem to work, is there any default method of vue for doing the same without using any third party library?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the router instance, you can provide the **scrollBehavior** function, which will help you to scroll to top when navigating to a new route:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
      // return desired position
  }
})
```

For more details, you can follow this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling